# How to use text result of a function outside of function and write it to Word document

Tags: python, list, function, printing, docx

My program (ideally) extracts from the web a list of elements and then sends the result to a Word doc, saves it and closes it.

All questions I find previously asked here don't cover this problem. How can I print the list text output of the function `var()` into at `p.runs[4]` in the Word file? I guess something about the `return` word would help? but nothing I've tried works.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

def var():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('https://jobs.theguardian.com/searchjobs/?LocationId=1500&keywords=personal+assistant&radialtown=London+(Central)%2c+London+(Greater)&countrycode=GB')
    #elem = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('lister__header')
    elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3/a/span')
    for el in elem:
        var.printText = print(el.text)
    browser.close()
var()

import docx
d = docx.Document('C:\\Users\\sk\\Desktop\\test.docx')
p = d.paragraphs[3]
p.runs[4].text = var.printText    #HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO PLACE THE TEXT LIST OUTPUT of var.printText

d.save('C:\\Users\\sk\\Desktop\\test.docx')
```

When I run this program, only the word "NONE" is written to the word file, and this is the console result:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/sk/PycharmProjects/test/temperase.py
Designer, The Labour Party
Graduate Display Marketing Account Manager
 # snip...
HR Administrator – Recruitment & Training
Secondary Teaching Assistant - Immediate start supporting across all subjects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sk/PycharmProjects/test/temperase.py", line 22, in <module>
    p.runs[4].text = var.printText
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\docx\text\run.py", line 163, in text
    self._r.text = text
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 104, in text
    _RunContentAppender.append_to_run_from_text(self, text)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 134, in append_to_run_from_text
    appender.add_text(text)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 141, in add_text
    for char in text:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What are you expecting `var.printText = print(el.text)` to do, exactly?! `print` returns `None`, and even if it returned what gets printed you're replacing the previous value each time. Why don't you try returning a list from `var` (bad function name, by the way), rather than assigning to an attribute?

Comment: Uhm...I'd like that variable to print the list of jobs inside the word document.I am not sure I understnad your second sentence. How do I return a list from var, exactly? I don't have enough code knowledge to be creative yet. LIke I said, I am new, so this is one of my first scripts with code borrowed from different places. I am still trying to work my head around it all. If you can, would you give me code that works so I learn from it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html